# How am I supposed to change the Bootstrap CSS properties in a new Yeoman project?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman

With a new Yeoman project are you supposed to leave the vendor CSS as is and override it using a new CSS file? I ask because the main.css file is created in /styles and the bootstrap.css file is buried down in the bower_components folder. I know that either way will work and that once the app is built all the CSS gets concatenated into one file. I just want to know what the best practice and/or what the Yeoman devs intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should override any vendor CSS with your own custom CSS file that gets loaded after the vendor CSS.  Hope this helps.